# How to pip install forex python

Tags: python, windows

I am attempting to install forex-python. I have attempted to find a meaningful answer to this question everywhere, however my search has been in vain. Now, the Python Software Foundation's instructions are to pip install it. I am currently using Python V3.6.1 and the Foundation states that versions 3.4 or greater have pip installed directly into them. I am using the executable installer of v3.6.1. 
My question is this: where do you pip install this package on Windows? I attempted to install the package in the python command prompt, tagged Python 3.6(64 bit), using the statement
    pip install forex-python
though it resulted in a syntax error.
Is the module supposed to be installed on the Python interpreter? Since I am using Windows Vista, what is the Windows version of a terminal? I am unaccustomed to a Windows operating system on a Toshiba computer and I am more familiar with Mac OS X. If there is a version, what is it called and how do I find it? And if it is supposed to be installed on the Python interpreter, why does it give a syntax error when I enter the statement? 
When I asked for help, it stated all information about pip, however it did not state how to install forex-python.
I currently have forex-python downloaded on this computer, symbolized by the logo of three books. It is complete with the code, readmes and files, however, I do not know how to install it for usage in IDLE programs, like my currency converter.
I would be very grateful for any help on this subject.

Answer (score 0):

you can try

```
pip install forex-python
```

or

```
pip install git+https://github.com/MicroPyramid/forex-python.git
```

then you can check the installation through

```
pip freeze
```

if it is listed in it then it is installed

Comment: I am sorry, but do I do this in the python interpreter? if not, then where? Thank you for your help.

Comment: do this in command prompt if using windows or in terminal if using ubuntu